# How should I redirect a user to the registration route instead of the login route when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried overwriting the authenticate_user method but it seems to result in an infinite loop

Comment: Can you elaborate? Under what conditions do you want to redirect a user to the registration route?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mess with the devise files unless you know what you're doing. You should use

`if current_user
  something
else
  link_to "Join up", new_user_registration_path`

Comment: This completely overwrites the authenticate_user method

Comment: It doesn't mess with the actual method though. That was the point. Essentially, it does the same thing without touching the devise file. That was my train of thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily as below:

Add a method called `authenticate_user!` which overrides the default method  to redirect the user to registration path if user not signed in..

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :unless => :devise_controller? # This prevent the infinite redirects.

    protected
    def authenticate_user!
      if !current_user
          redirect_to new_user_registration_path    
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: What if I want it global?

Comment: @Edward I have edited my answer to make it global check it.